# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin{(\cosh{x})}\cosh{x}}{1+\cosh^{2}{x}}dx$

Tags: definite-integrals, contour-integration, residue-calculus, hyperbolic-functions

I am attempting to solve the following definite integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin{(\cosh{x})}\cosh{x}}{1+\cosh^{2}{x}}dx.$$

I was trying passing to the complex plane and use the residue theorem, but I did not manage to find a satisfying contour. The half-circle seem to not work because the poles accumulate at infinity, while a rectangle does not because the integrand diverges on the vertical sides.

Which one is the right approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: I suspect that the equivalent form: $$2\int_1^\infty\frac{t\sin t}{1+t^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t-1}\sqrt{t+1}}\,\mathrm{d}t$$Is amenable to a dogbone method

Comment: The integral itself is Feynman trickable. From there a rectangular contour is easier.

Comment: @FShrike can you please give me a hint about the correct contour? i can't figure it out myself, each one I try has some problem. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I haven't so far been able to find a direct contour method for this integral. I'll keep trying when I get time. So far, I have only been able to use contour methods to deduce seemingly useless equalities such as: $$\frac{1}{2}J=\int_0^1\frac{x\cos x}{(1+x^2)\sqrt{1-x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x-\operatorname{P.V.}\,\int_0^\infty\frac{x\exp(-x)}{(x^2-1)\sqrt{1+x^2}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$Where $J$ is the desired integral

Comment: Now if you had $\cos(\cosh(x))$ in the numerator I think I could get it. But the sine is somehow annoying to deal with

Comment: Can I ask you, out of curiosity, which countour would be used for the $\cos$ case?

Comment: Never mind. I'm not even sure if I can do that. This particular integrand is extremely annoying; it's close to having the necessary symmetries but it doesn't quite. Probably Ninad's Feynman trick is overwhelmingly the easier way to go.

Comment: @NinadMunshi. So, you suggest I consider $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}-\frac{\cos{(t\cosh{x})}}{1+\cosh^{2}{x}}dx$$, right?

Comment: Yes that's the one!

Comment: Can you give me an hint about the contour? I still have no clue on how to go on from here.

Comment: @NinadMunshi I’m not convinced you can arrange for the rectangular contour to work there as you previously suggested. $\cosh(\sinh(-))$ would appear in the numerator which presumably dominates the denominator and you couldn’t really show that the  error decays

Comment: @FShrike you could be right, I'm just a little bit confused. Where does $\cosh(\sinh(\cdot))$ come into play?

Comment: @NinadMunshi On the vertical legs of a rectangular contour, considering: $$\cos(t\cosh(a+bi))=\cos(t\cosh(a)\cos(b)+it\sinh(a)\sin(b))=\cosh(t\sinh(a)\sin(b))\text{ and other terms }$$With $a$ large and $b$ variable, it’s unclear how to show the integral would vanish and it *looks* like it would blow up

Comment: To the OP: *does this have a closed form?* Was this integral given in a problem set, or did you make it up for fun to see if it was possible?

Comment: No, I have no clue if it has a closed form. It was not given in a problem set. So it can surely be the case it does not have a closed form. Anyway I would be happy also if the result includes special functions of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the integral has a closed form. The substitution $t=\cosh x$ gives \begin{align}I&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\cosh x\sin\cosh x}{1+\cosh^2x}\,dx\\&=2\int_1^\infty\frac{t\sin t}{(t^2+1)\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt\\&=2\int_1^\infty\frac{t\sin t+\sinh1}{(t^2+1)\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt-2\int_1^\infty\frac{\sinh1}{(t^2+1)\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,dt\\&=2\int_1^\infty\int_0^1\frac{\cos ut\cosh(u-1)}{\sqrt{t^2-1}}\,du\,dt-\sqrt2\log(1+\sqrt2)\sinh1\\&=-\pi\int_0^1Y_0(u)\cosh(u-1)\,du-\sqrt2\log(1+\sqrt2)\sinh1\end{align} We therefore seek a closed form for $\int_0^1Y_0(u)e^u\,du$. However, as the upper limit of $1$ is not a special value of the Bessel function of the second kind, this amounts to a closed form for the indefinite integral which I doubt is known.